# Highcharts Map fill pattern

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am unable to add a pattern to Highcharts Continents Map. I want to add a circle with SVG path `M 5 5 m -4 0 a 4 4 0 1 1 8 0 a 4 4 0 1 1 -8 0` https://jsfiddle.net/xt2sufvb/31/. I want to fill the complete map with this vector just like this https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/dotted-world-map-vector-illustration-design-circles-earth-globe-160650521.jpg.

Comment: This doesn’t seem related to angular?

Comment: @MikeOne It is. This same javascript code can be used in Angular too. I have to implement this graph in Angular.

Comment: Hi @ctaneja, Maybe disabled map borders will be enough? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/axqj2mfk/ If not, please check tilemap series type. Example: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/circlemap-africa